# How do I connect and how to export login/register data from an Adobe XD Login/Register Prototype to a database?

Tags: mysql, database, connection, adobe-xd

So a friend of mine designed a full website in Adobe XD including a Login/Register form BUT we don't know how to connect it to a database (easiest way ) and what should we use to export the data. We want the data that the users will put in the forms to aslo be verified, like if it matches the email form, or the passwords have letters and numbers. Some steps to follow and what should we use will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to convert the adobexd design to working html/css. You can do that with Desech Studio.

Once you have your website done with html/css, you then need to use client side javascript to make api calls to fetch data for login, etc. But this api is something you need to create with node.js as the programming language and with postgresql as your database.

All these are just examples. You can use different programming languages and databases on your backend. But the HTML/CSS/Javascript is mandatory because that's what websites are built with in the end.